# Adding a row vector and a column vector

Tags: matlab, vector, sum

I need to add two variables which have different dimensions in MATLAB.

`A` has dimensions 1*60

`B` has dimensions 60*1

Since the matrix dimensions are not same, I cannot sum them by using the sum command. I would like to ask if there is any way to add them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [transpose function `.'`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) or the [colon operator `(:)`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)

Do not include these two lines of code, they are just set-up for this example:

```
A = ones(1, 60);  % create an arbitrary row vector 1x60
B = ones(60, 1);  % create an arbitrary column vector 60x1
```

Choose **one** of these options, a comment above each describes what it does.

```
% output a vector the same orientation as A
C = A + B.';

% output a vector the same orientation as B
C = A.' + B;

% output a column vector, no matter the orientation of A and B 
% Ensure that they are vectors, this will give undesired results if A and B are 2D.
C = A(:) + B(:);
```